# Connecting to DB instance in Private subnet from outside VPC

Tags: amazon-rds

I would like to create a DB instance in a private subnet that does not have access to internet. However, during the development stages of my application, I would like to connect to it from my PC over the internet. When everything is complete, I would like to disallow public access to the instance and let it be accessed only from within the VPC.

I tried creating an instance in the private subnet and configured it for public access. It would not allow me to do so and that is obvious.

Is there a way an Elastic Network Interface from a public subnet can be attached to the RDS instance so that it can be accessed publicly during development phases?